# Data import Handler in Solr 3.6.2 on tomcat

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, solr, dataimporthandler

I have a requirement to create a Solr search on the database. I am using Solr 3.6.2 which is already deployed Tomcat. I am able to access Solr admin page. But it is entirely different. I know how to add data import handler Solr 6.2  by configuring `solrconfig.xml` and `schema.xml` and `data-config.xml`. But I want to know how we have to configure the same on Tomcat.

In fact, I don't know where we have to create a collection and then configure database.

Comment: Do you want to migrate to 6.2 and use the solr with tomcat? SOLR 6 is now a standalone server and does not provide war file to be deployed in any other container.

Comment: You can't create a "collection" on 3.6.2, as the whole concept of collections was first introduced with the cloud mode in 4.0. In pre-4.0 you'll only have to reference a "core". Check the admin interface for the location of the index / data / home dir, and start by looking there for the proper configuration files. The DIH configuration should be more or less identical to how you'd configure it for 6.2.

Comment: Thanks. I am using SOLR 6.2. With standalone mode, I am able  to configure DB. Also, I want to know how to insert the data using SOLR API into the database. Also, Can you suggest any website for SOLR cloud data import handler?